# My Indian visa says I will enter the country "by air". Can I still use it to enter by train?

Tags: visas, air-travel, india, bangladeshi-citizens

I am from Bangladesh. I have been granted a visa to go to India. On the visa, it is noted that I would enter the country "by air." Am I also also to travel via train?

Comment: Related, but I don't think a duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62716/traveling-from-bangladesh-to-india-by-train

Comment: I can't cite any source, but my answer would ne

Comment: Have you tried contacting [Indian high Commission](https://www.hcidhaka.gov.in/pages.php?id=14) in Dhaka through e-mail and asking this question?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm trying to find an official source. In the meantime here is a news article about something similar - http://www.livemint.com/Politics/IrtgjXtbqpwiXR5UdXblhL/A-year-on-Maitree-Express-becomes-an-ordeal-to-avoid.html

Comment: I used a dual-entry visa that said "By Air - Kolkata Only" (the only visa the embassy in Mandalay would give me) to enter once overland from Myanmar and once on the Maitree Express. The India official at the border with Myanmar (once I found him - it was a Sunday and he was at home) said nothing. The guys at the India checkpoint on the border with Bangladesh were a bit concerned about it, but just wanted to know why I wasn't flying and I said my plans changed. It wasn't a problem in the end. YMMV of course...

Answer (score 19):

No, you aren't allowed to enter India by train if your didn't explicitly make a request for the same during your visa application.

Please review the [visa requirements for Maitree Express](https://www.hcidhaka.gov.in/pages.php?id=1225). This page is available in both `English` and `Bangla`.

I've also reproduced the relevant section here for reference -

> Visa requirement
>
> A valid passport and visa are required to travel by Maitree Express.
> To travel by Maitree Express the passenger has to choose one of the
> following options in the online visa form:
>
> - By Rail Gede
> - By Rail Gede/By Air
> - By Rail Gede / By Road Haridaspur
>
> Passport and visa have to be
> shown at the ticket counter at the time of purchase and a copy of the
> same is to be submitted.

Comment: +1 To add to this answer, while applying for visa from Bangladesh, applicants must choose the port f entry. The drop-down menu is [something like this](http://imgur.com/a/tqKqT). There are distinct categories "By Air" and "By rail Gede/By Air". Thus unless the applicant has chosen "By Rail gede/By Air" and ot the simple "By Air", he cannot take the Maitree express.

Comment: While this answer was right when it was posted, it might be outdated by now. So do double check if you want to travel in a different way to your visa.

Answer (score 8):

According to the latest changes( in **2017-2018**),

Any **Travel Visa** (*No matter **which port of entry, or route** you chose during VISA application*) issued to **Bangladeshi citizens** will allow the traveler to

1. Travel by train
2. Travel by air
3. Travel by road at Benapole-Haridashpur border.

It does not matter **when** you got the Travel VISA, you are allowed for the **3 routes mentioned above**.

It might be confusing because, after the announcement, the Visa authority is now printing this in the Passport(VISA page). But, those who got the Visa **before**, are also **eligible** for this.

So, now, if you choose a *route of entry*, it means **additional permission**. For example, you chose, *Tamabil-Dauki* border, then, you will be allowed to enter by this *Tamabil* border **along** with the above 3 options.

One reference: [Dhaka tribune news](https://www.dhakatribune.com/bangladesh/foreign-affairs/2017/07/25/india-removes-entry-exit-restrictions-bangladeshis)